# Numpy floor float values to int

Tags: python, numpy, math, floor

I have array of floats, and I want to floor them to nearest integer, so I can use them as indices.

For example:

```
In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: arr = np.random.rand(1, 10) * 10

In [4]: arr
Out[4]:
array([[4.97896461, 0.21473121, 0.13323678, 3.40534157, 5.08995577,
        6.7924586 , 1.82584208, 6.73890807, 2.45590354, 9.85600841]])

In [5]: arr = np.floor(arr)

In [6]: arr
Out[6]: array([[4., 0., 0., 3., 5., 6., 1., 6., 2., 9.]])

In [7]: arr.dtype
Out[7]: dtype('float64')
```

They are still floats after flooring, is there a way to automatically cast them to integers?

Answer (score 15):

I am edit answer with @DanielF explanation:
"floor doesn't convert to integer, it just gives integer-valued floats, so you still need an astype to change to int"
Check this code to understand the solution:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.random.rand(1, 10) * 10
print(arr)
arr = np.floor(arr).astype(int)
print(arr)
```

```
OUTPUT:
[[2.76753828 8.84095843 2.5537759  5.65017407 7.77493733 6.47403036
  7.72582766 5.03525625 9.75819442 9.10578944]]
[[2 8 2 5 7 6 7 5 9 9]]
```

Comment: Try and give some explanation and not just code.  Even just starting with "`floor` doesn't convert to integer, it just gives integer-valued `float`s, so you still need an `astype` to change  to `int`" will keep the review queue off your back.

Answer (score 2):

As alternative to changing type after floor division, you can provide an output array of the desired data type to `np.floor` (and to any other numpy ufunc). For example, imagine you want to convert the output to `np.int32`, then do the following:

```py
import numpy as np
arr = np.random.rand(1, 10) * 10
out = np.empty_like(arr, dtype=np.int32)
np.floor(arr, out=out, casting='unsafe')
```

As the casting argument already indicates, you should know what you are doing when casting outputs into different types. However, in your case it is not really unsafe.

Although, I would not call `np.floor` in your case, because all values are greater than zero. Therefore, the simplest and probably fastest solution to your problem would be a direct casting to integer.

```py
import numpy as np
arr = (np.random.rand(1, 10) * 10).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use:

```
np.random.randint(1,10)
```

Comment: This is close enough to an answer for me not to flag it, but this should probably be a comment once you get those privileges.  It's not *really* addressing the question, but could be a parallel solution.

Comment: The arguments `1` and `10` here have a very different meaning to those in `np.random.rand(1, 10)`: there the arguments are the shape of the resulting array; here you're asking for a single result and `1` and `10` give the bounds. It's not at all clear that the OP wants integers in the range 1 through 10. (I've asked for a clarification in a comment.)

Comment: @DanielF  Yes this was supposed to be a comment, but could not comment because i havent unlocked it.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Well if you use the size parameter you can get an array with a size ( ex: parameters for randint (low=0,high=10,size=10)), And as he wants to use them as indices im guessing that it is a whole number is what i he wants. But I agree he could specify that.